# sending sms from java web app using aws sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

A user will create an account on my web app.  The app will need to authenticate the user by sending a text message to the mobile phone number that the user provides.  The text message is a short unique code, which the user will need to type in to the web browser in order for the app to authenticate the user.

**How can I configure Amazon AWS SNS for this use case?**

From what I have read, SNS works by the webmaster selecting a `topic` and then each user subscribes to that topic.  Then the webmaster sends messages broadcast style to all the subscribers to the topic.  This would not meet my requirements of sending a unique message to each user.  Alternatively, creating a separate `topic` for every phone number would be too cumbersome, not to mention creating security issues with respect to protecting the privacy of all the phone numbers.

**Can Amazon AWS SNS be configured for this use case?  If so, how?**

I am using Java.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask AWS support for the supported use cases! Are they that bad that you have to fallback to stackoverflow.

Comment: @sureshkoya AWS support costs $100 per month. So users rely on stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

SNS topics are only nedded when you need to send a SMS message to multiple mobile numbers. If you want to send a SMS message to a single number you can use the Amazon AWS SDK.

Docs are available at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html#sms_publish_sdk.

Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("YOUR_Client_ID", "YOUR_Client_secret");
    final AmazonSNSClient client = new AmazonSNSClient(awsCredentials);
    client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.REGION_YOU_WANT_TO_USE));

    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(awsCredentials);
    String message = "My SMS message";
    String phoneNumber = "+1XXX5550100";
    Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = 
            new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
    //<set SMS attributes>
    sendSMSMessage(snsClient, message, phoneNumber, smsAttributes);
}

public static void sendSMSMessage(AmazonSNSClient snsClient, String message, 
    String phoneNumber, Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes) {
    PublishResult result = snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest()
                    .withMessage(message)
                    .withPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    .withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes));
    System.out.println(result); // Prints the message ID.
}
```

Remember to create an user on IAM console adding a permission to access the SNS Service. You need to add **AmazonSNSFullAccess** role.

Replace **YOUR_Client_ID** and **YOUR_Client_secret** with user credentials you have created.

Comment: could you please let me know the exact jar version you used for the above code..?

Answer (score 4):

Some methods have been deprecated in AWS SDK.

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("CLIENT-ID", "SECRET-KEY");
AmazonSNS snsClient = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
                     .withRegion(Regions.fromName("YOUR_REGION"))
     .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build();

Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID",new MessageAttributeValue().withStringValue("SENDER-ID").withDataType("String"));
smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType",new MessageAttributeValue().withStringValue("Transactional").withDataType("String"));

PublishRequest request = new PublishRequest();
request.withMessage("YOUR MESSAGE")
.withPhoneNumber("E.164-PhoneNumber")
.withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes);
PublishResult result=snsClient.publish(request);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sending an SMS using the AWS SDK for Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient();
        String message = "My SMS message";
        String phoneNumber = "+1XXX5550100";
        Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = 
                new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
        //<set SMS attributes>
        sendSMSMessage(snsClient, message, phoneNumber, smsAttributes);
}

public static void sendSMSMessage(AmazonSNSClient snsClient, String message, 
        String phoneNumber, Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes) {
        PublishResult result = snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest()
                        .withMessage(message)
                        .withPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                        .withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes));
        System.out.println(result); // Prints the message ID.
}
```

---

For this particular use case you should consider the AWS Customer Engagement Service **Amazon Pinpoint**. It allows sending SMS, emails and push notifications, with tools for marketing campaigns as well as analytics:

[Amazon Pinpoint Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/welcome.html)

The documentation includes a tutorial for your specific use case:

[Setting Up an SMS Registration System Using Amazon Pinpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/tutorials-two-way-sms.html)

For what you described, while it could be done using SNS with the AWS SDK for Java, Pinpoint is designed to interact with application users, so it's probably a better alternative

Answer (score -3):

Individual SMS/MMS messaging is outside the apparent use cases of AWS SNS.

If you need to send proper SMS/MMS text messages to arbitrary phone numbers, you'll need to turn to other platforms, such as [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) or [Bandwidth](http://www.bandwidth.com/mobile-platform).

Comment: Disagree. `AWS SNS` completely support sending transactional SMS meant for single phone numbers.

Comment: @ShubhamA. AWS SNS didn't support this back in 2015. It was only recently that they supported sending transnational SMS messages to phone numbers instead of topics. However, Otávio Garcia provides a way that this can be done now.

Comment: AWS SNS _still_ doesn't support MMS.