# AWS SNS OTP emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am working on sending OTP messages for user login leveraging Amazon SNS. I am able to send Text message as suggesting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466916/sending-sms-from-java-web-app-using-aws-sns). For the email notification as well I would like to use a similar approach. But looks like for email notifications, a topic has to be created in SNS and a subscriber has to be created for each email id registered in the application.

Is it not possible to send email to mail-id dynamically as done for text messages without creating topics and subscribers? If not please suggest a way to set email id dynamically based on the user logged in.

Code for Text Messaging:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient();
    String message = "My SMS message";
    String phoneNumber = "+1XXX5550100";
    Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = 
            new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
    //<set SMS attributes>
    sendSMSMessage(snsClient, message, phoneNumber, smsAttributes);
 }
 public static void sendSMSMessage(AmazonSNSClient snsClient, String message, 
    String phoneNumber, Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes) {
    PublishResult result = snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest()
                    .withMessage(message)
                    .withPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    .withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes));
    System.out.println(result); // Prints the message ID.
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct.

Amazon SNS normally uses a Public/Subscribe model for messages.

The one exception is the ability to send an SMS message to a specific recipient.

If you wish to send an email to a single recipient, you will need to **use your own SMTP server**, or use Amazon Simple Email Service (**Amazon SES**).